# Can I use Tor through UDP Protocol?

Tags: configuration, windows

I am using internet using 3G Data Card and my network have UDP 53 port open even when I don't have Internet plans. How can I use configure Tor to use UDP 53 port for Internet access.

Comment: I thought that Tor works only with TCP? I think outgoing UDP is definitely not allowed, or do you mean listening for incoming packets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tor relies on TCP,please see more details about how Tor works in https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en ,notice " Tor only works for TCP streams and can be used by any application with SOCKS support."So you can`t use Tor through UDP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Port 53 is the only udp port supported by Tor and it works by making Tor listen on that port and transcribe dns requests over the network. Only DNS requests are supported, so that is the only way you are going to be able to use it. Also no icmp so ping will still go through untorrified which could leak your info.

Answer (score 1):

as others have pointed out, tor works on top of tcp, but if you want to tunnel through port 53, you might want to check out http://code.kryo.se/iodine/ at least if you have a server available. it only gives you a connection to your server but you can tunnel out from there. don't expect speed, and depending on your ISPs DNS server it might not even work at all.